# Can I use mixed effects models on heteroscedastic data? Why?

Tags: mixed-model, heteroscedasticity

Is it a problem to use mixed effects models on heterocedastic data? I have read contradictory information about it. For example, Zuur's book "Mixed effects models and extensions in ecology with R" and this [post](https://jonlefcheck.net/2013/03/13/r2-for-linear-mixed-effects-models/) where they say:

> The authors also note (and I echo) that looking at R2 and AIC values is not a replacement for testing basic model assumptions, such as normality of predictors and non-constant variance, and should be used in tandem.

If it is not an issue, why? If it is, how could I solve the problem?

Comment: The quote only says that basic assumptions like constant variance should still be **checked**.  Typical modeling tools like transformations can still be used with mixed effects model, and models with non-constant variance can be used, the question is if you will find software that implements it.  What the quote does **not** say is that mixed models cannot be used with heteroskedasticity.

Comment: What do you mean with 'if it is not an issue'? Where does 'it' refer to? The same book contains plenty of examples in which mixed models are applied on heterogeneous data. We just added a varIdent or so.

Comment: "normality of predictors" has never been an assumption relevant to linear models.

Comment: There's likely no omnibus. Are/is your model(s) for inference or prediction? Model checking has separate issues of generating its own false positive/negatives. Checking assumptions is a separate issue from applying robust methods that do not require them.